# Setting a texture on only one object in scene

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to opengl and I have this puppet (head,torso,legs,arms) and I would like to set the texture on only the torso part of this puppet.

I was under the assumption that before I draw the torso portion of my puppet I can simply call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and after drawing call `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`, but I seem to be getting a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

// Code for loading textures called in an init function at startup

```
void loadTextures()
{

    // load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
}
```

// Code for drawing the puppet

```
void A3::renderNode(const SceneNode * root, mat4 view, mat4 model) {
    if (root == nullptr) return;

    mat4 tmp_model = model * root->get_transform();
    if (root->m_nodeType == NodeType::GeometryNode) {

        const GeometryNode * geometryNode = static_cast<const GeometryNode *>(root);

        updateShaderUniforms(m_shader, *geometryNode, view, tmp_model , picking);

        // Get the BatchInfo corresponding to the GeometryNode's unique MeshId.
        BatchInfo batchInfo = m_batchInfoMap[geometryNode->meshId];

        m_shader.enable();

        if (root->m_name == "torso")
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, batchInfo.startIndex, batchInfo.numIndices);

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        m_shader.disable();

    } 

    for (const SceneNode * node : root->children) {
        renderNode(node, view, tmp_model); // recursion
    }
}
```

Comment: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` does only have an effect if you don't use a shader. For modern OpenGL, you should be able to configure your shader accordingly (or use a different one).

Comment: @NicoSchertler ohh i see that makes a lot more sense, I guess I can use a uniform value to inform my shaders, thank you!

Comment: @user11777831 Create a 1x1 texture with the color you want to use for the not textured meshes.

Comment: Probably best to compile another version of your shader that does not use a texture and use that second version shader for all geometry that you want to render without the texture. Use the original shader for your "torso" geometry.